# RavenDB : "Make sure the port is open."

Tags: nosql, port, ravendb, firewall, windows-firewall

I want to set up a 4.0.4 RavenDB through its setup wizard but it keeps saying that my port 443 isn't open.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/207qT.png)

In my [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTLSX.png) I've double-checked the IP adresses. 
192.168.1.28 is my computer.
Everything's fine. 38889 was just a test.

In my [Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE4Ae.png) port settings, everything looks ok : [NAT/PAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DgPO.png)

Same thing with the [Windows Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8rS8.png)

Btw, before you link it to me, I've already read 
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/server/security/common-errors-and-faq

If anyone could help, i'd provide lifetime gratitude :)

Thank you in advance for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that something is holding on to that port.
This is frequently `Skype` or `IIS`.
Here is how you can figure it (PowerShell):

```
PS C:\> Get-Process -id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 443).OwningProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   1855      78   136472      76416   2,115.61  12812   1 Skype
```

On My Machine, you can see that `Skype` is indeed holding this port open. You can change that using:

[image: Skype configuration]

Comment: Was indeed the solution. Took 6 months to mark it as answer.

Happy new year x)